# Android Google map with nearby places

Tags: android, google-maps, google-nearby

I am using Android Studio latest version and SDK version 23.0.0
When I follow this link to get a nearby map application nothing happens, and it only shows that your Unfortunately your app has stopped. The link is

http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2013/03/google-places-api-tutorial.html

and I think a lot of links I followed did not help in creating a nearby places application, any one please help me.

Comment: please post your stack trace, and refer to the official API doc reference for maps instead of this third party to get started https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: For the nearby places, you can just use the code [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlacePicker). It's new and don't forget put your API-KEY in `AndroidMenifest`

Comment: inner_class7 i have allready apply your suggestion please give another solution or provide me the run  code for understanding

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is based on the Places API Web Service.

We recently released [Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android/), which includes [PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace()](https://developers.google.com/places/android/current-place).

Example:

```
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
    .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
    for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
      Log.i(TAG, String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
          placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
          placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
    }
    likelyPlaces.release();
  }
});
```

You will also need to enable Places API for Android in the Google Developers Console and add an Android API key to your AndroidManifest.xml. See the [setup instructions here](https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Francois Wouts I has many time follow that process which shown by u link ....but i m not getting success please another help .         here two lines are symbolized by logcat                        .....                                               (1).        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){                       (2).  private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{